# How to fix duplicate insertions to a DB from deploy app in Jboss domain mode?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jboss

I'm running Jboss in domain mode with the default settings, and deploying a war to the `main-server-group` and by default to the two servers`server-one, server-two`.
I want to insert into a DB the data from the app running in the server side but as it is running in two servers I get duplicated insertions to the DB, I'm using MySQL.

Since the deployment on both servers is at the same time I can not check if it is already inserted in the db.

Is there a query that allows me to check before I insert in MySQL?

Or maybe I can get in what server is running `(server-one or server-two)` and insert into the DB only if it is running in `server-one`, but how do I get in what server the app is running?

Comment: Do a load from an external source?  Is it loading on initialization or something?  What happens if you need to restart the servers?  Beyond that, `INSERT`s in every RDBMS I'm aware of allow `SELECT`s as part of the statement, meaning that it will 'ignore' existing rows...

Comment: It is validating if it is already in the DB, so when the servers are restarted it does not insert it again. Yes it is loading on initialization.

Comment: _Why_ is it loading the data on initialization?  That's probably **not** the best time.  What does this data represent?  Why can't you load it to your DB _once_ (as an separate command), and then you wouldn't need to worry about 'duplicates'; it sounds like you have things too tightly coupled between application and data.  Otherwise... what's to stop you just executing a standard `SELECT` statement first?

Comment: How may a `INSERT SELECT` query may be? so that it only insert if it not exists. 
It is a simple table like this:
`CREATE TABLE table
(
  id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)`

Comment: It have to register automatically when it is deployed

Answer (score 1):

To `INSERT` a row only if it doesn't exist, you can use something akin to the following (may need to be tweaked for mySQL, I don't have an instance):

```
INSERT INTO Registrar (name) (SELECT name
                              FROM (VALUES ('NEW'), ('EXISTING')) as tmp(name)
                              WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1'
                                                FROM Registrar
                                                WHERE Registrar.name = tmp.name))
```

(Working [SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e71518/8) - please note this was run against PostgreSQL, because the mySQL window wouldn't allow the `INSERT`).

If you have too many rows to `INSERT` to generate the `VALUES` statement, stick them into a temp (cleanup on disconnect) table, then use that reference instead of the `VALUES` reference.

Anyways, I'm still a little suspicious about what you're trying to do...

Comment: Tip for MySQL on SQL Fiddle - run your inserts/updates/deletes in the schema (left) panel, possibly into new or temporary tables.  Then, on the right side, you can see the results of those by just selecting from them.  It's an unfortunate limitation of MySQL, but doing this kind of thing works around most of them.

Comment: @Jake - In this case, I wanted to show the 'original' state of the table, before the `INSERT`, and I don't think SQL Fiddle allows (standalone) `SELECT` statements in the left panel...

Comment: You could keep the original table unmodified, but insert into a new table.  Then you could just select from one then the other in the right panel to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the insertion with an HA Singleton by implemting a Singleton service.
Here is an example: http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/cluster-ha-singleton/